# What is the null vector for a metric?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, causality

I am studying the Robertson Walker metric. I now understand what the geodesic looks like but what is a null vector of the geodesic? Is it just the tangent vector to the geodesic curve?

Comment: What is the definition of : outgoing?

Comment: Is null vector $v\colon g(v,v)=0$ ? What does "of the geodesic" mean, is it tangent spaces on the points of the geodesic you think about?

Comment: Why are you using a definite article here? There's infinitely many geodesics (some of them null, others not) and infinitely many null vectors, what's the context here?

Comment: On a light-like geodesic - or the geodesic of a massless particle - it's the tangent vector to the geodesic.